# Update stored procedure not working in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update the status by changing the bool value from 1 to 0. I am passing the user id to the stored procedure. I just need to update the user status only. But now it's not doing that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStatus]
    @userID INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[User]
    SET Status = 0 
    WHERE Id = @userID
END
```

I am calling this stored procedure:

```
public User UpdateStatus(string UserId)
{
        User userDetails = new User();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateStatus", sqlConnection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", UserId));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                           userDetails.DisplayName = reader["DisplayName"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //ex.Message;
        }

        return userDetails;
}
```

I am calling the `UpdateStatus` function. But it's not updating the status in the database

Comment: An UPDATE statement doesn't return a reader to read something

Comment: *"but it does not returning anything."* Why would it? The Procedure isn't returning a dataset. The only thing you'll get back from that proc would be the `RETURN` status, which'll likely be `0` for success.

Comment: It should be executenonquery. And you should make a select in another query.

Comment: Well, if the OP *did* need data back, they would likely be able to use an `OUTPUT` clause, @MonkeyDLuffy

Comment: @Larnu its  not updating the database.so the return status is 0 and expected is 1

Answer (score 1):

I am basing this answer purely on guess work from this comment:

> its not updating the database.so the return status is 0 and expected is 1

An `UPDATE` that updates `0` rows without an error is still a successful statement . I suspect you are passing a value for `@userID` where there is no row that has that value for an `ID`. That won't cause the `RETURN` status to be `1`, or anything else. If you want a failure to occur when no rows are updated then check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT`. and then `THROW` or `RETURN`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStatus] @userID INT AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[User]
    SET Status=0 
    WHERE Id = @userID;

    --RETURN example
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN 1; --Denote "failure"
    ELSE
        RETURN 0; --Denote Success

    --Or perhaps you want to THROW
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        THROW 89001, N'No rows were updated.',10; --USe a custom Error code appropriate for your application

END;
```

Comment: how can i use this  @@ROWCOUNT in the c# code.what i have tried is     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", UserId);
                    var effectedRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@@ROWCOUNT"].Value);                                                  this got an exception.

Comment: Huh? `@@ROWCOUNT` is a system variable in SQL Server, you can't access it in the C#. It's handled in the Procedure. If you want the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` returned the  you could use an `OUTPUT` parameter, but that's a **completely different question**.

Comment: will you plz provide any useful meterial for that

Comment: [how to use SQL Server OUTPUT parameters in C#](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+SQL+Server+OUTPUT+parameters+in+C%23) @developer.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the rowcount anyway, so long as `NOCOUNT OFF`